# Open IE and send JSON POST data

Tags: json, powershell

I'm trying using PowerShell to open a web page while sending JSON as my POST data.

Here is what I have

```
$ie = New-Object -comObject InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.visible = $true
$postBytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Default.GetBytes('"xCoord":"11.11","yCoord":"22.22","scale":"8,000,016.00","coordSysId":"123"');
$ie.navigate("http://localhost/ProcessSearch", "_blank", $postBytes, "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8")
```

The web page does open however the JSON isn't getting posted according to Fiddler.

How can I send the POST data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been looking at something similar and I've posted this http://amonkeysden.tumblr.com/post/5842982257/posting-to-a-restful-api-with-powershell - there's a link to the source there as well but more specifically this is the module:

https://bitbucket.org/thompsonson/powershellmodulerepository/src/5e0afe9d0e26/PsUrl/PsUrl.psm1

and you probably want the `New-RestItem` function though the `Write-URL` might do it for you as well.

You should pass the JSON as a string - the example below isn't tested... :).

eg.

`New-RestItem http://www.tumblr.com/api/write -Data @{"JSON" = '{"something": "value", "more": {"morekey1":"value", "morekey2": "value"} }'`

```
function New-RestItem {
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true, Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]    
    [String]$Url,
    [HashTable]$Data,
    [TimeSpan]$Timeout = [System.TimeSpan]::FromMinutes(1)
)    
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web
    $formData = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::ParseQueryString("")  
    foreach($key in $Data.Keys){
        $formData.Add($key, $Data[$key])        
    }
    Write-Verbose $formData.ToString()
    $reqBody = [System.Text.Encoding]::Default.GetBytes($formData.ToString())   

    try{
        $req = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($Url)
        $req.Method = "POST"
        $req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"      
        $req.Timeout = $Timeout.TotalMilliseconds
        $reqStream = $req.GetRequestStream()        
        $reqStream.Write($reqBody, 0, $reqBody.Length)
        $reqStream.Close()

        $resp = $req.GetResponse()
        Write-Verbose $resp
        Write-Output $resp.StatusCode
    }
    catch [System.Net.WebException]{
        if ($_.Exception -ne $null -and $_.Exception.Response -ne $null) {
            $errorResult = $_.Exception.Response.GetResponseStream()
            $errorText = (New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($errorResult)).ReadToEnd()
            Write-Warning "The remote server response: $errorText"
            Write-Output $_.Exception.Response.StatusCode
        } else {
            throw $_
        }
    }   

<#
.Synopsis
    POSTs the data to the given URL
.Description     
    POSTs the data to the given URL and returns the status code
.Parameter Url
    URL to POST
.Parameter Data
    Hashtable of the data to post.
.Parameter Timeout
    Optional timeout value, by default timeout is 1 minute.
.Input
    URL and a hash of the data to create
.Output
    The HTTP Status code (Created (201), Forbidden (403) or Bad Request (400))
.Example
    PS:> New-RestItem http://www.tumblr.com/api/write -Data @{"Foo" = "Bar" }

    Description
    -----------
    POST's data to the tumblr write API as application/x-www-form-urlencoded

#>
}
```

Comment: Holy mother! This looks great. Once I have a minute I'll test it out. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the cURL utility http://curl.haxx.se/dlwiz/?type=bin&os=Win64 and run it from PowerShell. No need to use IE or any browser for that matter.

Comment: That looks like a slick library. I'll be looking at it for future projects. Thank you.